# Mule Soft Database Select Query with In Where Condition

Tags: sql, database, select, mule, mule4

I am trying to bring all employee details by passing employee id in select query. unfortunately i am not able to get pass list of employee ids.

I have list of employee ids in Array

```
employee_ids=[100,101,200,2003,400]
```

In mule i am trying to get all employee details using flowing query

```
<db:select config-ref="mysql_Configuration" doc:name="get Employee details">
            <db:sql>
                select * from employee where employee_id in (:EMP_IDS)
            </db:sql>
            <db:input-parameters>
               #[{'EMP_IDS' : vars.listEmployeeIds}]
            </db:input-parameters>          

        </db:select>
```

It is throwing an error :

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Invalid column type.
Error type            : DB:QUERY_EXECUTION
```

I also try to pass all employee id with comma separate value

Where value of

```
listEmployeeIds =[100,101,200,2003,400] joinBy ","
```

Result = "100,101,200,2003,400"

```
<db:select config-ref="mysql_Configuration" doc:name="get Employee details">
                <db:sql>
                    select * from employee where employee_id in (:EMP_IDS)
                </db:sql>
                <db:input-parameters>
                   #[{'EMP_IDS' : vars.listEmployeeIds}]
                </db:input-parameters>          

            </db:select>
```

But its also giving me error 
As indirectly its converting into String so it is giving me:

```
Message               : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: invalid number
.
Error type            : DB:BAD_SQL_SYNTAX
```

Can anyone help me to resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work that way because the Database connector uses JDBC to implement the queries, and JDBC doesn't support parameterization of the IN clause. You can use the alternative method described in the following MuleSoft KB article https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-use-dynamic-IN-clause-in-your-query-statement-using-Database-Connector