# How to create a dynamic SQL query based on dynamic input parameters in Mulesoft

Tags: sql, dataweave, mulesoft

We have to write a SQL query with dynamic input parameters in Mulesoft.

Input:

```
{
    "supplier_id": "100",
    "supplier_name": "Microsoft",
    "city": [ "Redmond", "Mountain View", "Redwood City" ]
}
```

Here input is dynamic where value of city might differ.

Output:

```
select id, name, city 
from db.supplier 
where id = '100' 
  and (city = 'Redmond' or city = 'Mountain View' or city = 'Redwood City')
```

I tried to update as `IN` condition but it is not working so only way is to repeat the column and value with `OR` condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mule Soft Database Select Query with In Where Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58924150/mule-soft-database-select-query-with-in-where-condition)

Comment: Thank you for your response @aled, I used the below joinBy and it worked.
"('" ++ (payload.city joinBy "','") ++ "')"

Comment: Be aware of potential SQL injection vulnerabilities when using any kind of concatenation in SQL queries.